# Error creating android debug build in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Release build in my project is working fine. Debug build with local server ( ip address ) is also working fine. But when I create debug build with main bundle main.jsbundle. It is showing following error.

React native version mismatch.

Javascript version 0.50.4

Native version 0.55.4

What I have tried :

1. watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache.
2. Restart npm start
3. compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4") { force = true } // added force
4. Everything in this issue : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19259

Answer (score 0):

I've run into these problems before and what solved it for me was honestly to delete all of my libraries and `npm install` them again, the nodejs seems to be running a different version than react-native is and that's what is causing this issue. Make sure your package.json has the correct version as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile using JS 0.50.4 instead of 0.55.4 `compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.50.4") { force = true }`. I hope this my help